# Query Powerbuilder for some checkbox and input text/singelineedit for showig messagebox

Tags: powerbuilder

I have 3 checkboxes and 1 input text.

If I click a checkbox and I enter some text in input text, then I don't want the messagebox to appear.

If I don't click a checkbox but I input text then the messagebox should display.

My question is "How do I do that in Powerbuilder?"

Here is my code:

```
if Not IsNull(f_na) or Not IsNull(f_dep) or Not IsNull(f_krd) and IsNull (c_ao) then
    messagebox ('Perhatian','Kode AO baru harus diisi')
    return
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

If any checkbox being checked will prevent the message from showing after entering text, then:
If it's a SingleLineEdit or MultiLineEdit control, then in the `modified` event handler of the text control (i.e., a SingleLineEdit control):

```
String ls_EditControlText

ls_EditControlText = this.Text

// If the text is not empty, and none of the checkboxes are checked, then 
// show a message and clear the input
IF NOT IsNull(ls_EditControlText) AND (ls_EditControlText <> "") THEN
    // f_na, f_dep, and f_krd are the Checkbox controls
    IF NOT (f_na.Checked OR f_dep.Checked OR f_krd.Checked) THEN
        MessageBox("Attention", "A new AO code must be filled in")

        this.Text = ""  // clear the input
    END IF
END IF

RETURN
```

For an Edit or EditMask control on a DataWindow, you would the `itemchanged` event handler for the DataWindow control:

```
String ls_EditControlText

ls_EditControlText = data

// If the text is not empty, and none of the checkboxes are checked, then 
// show a message and clear the input
IF NOT IsNull(ls_EditControlText) AND (ls_EditControlText <> "") THEN
    // f_na, f_dep, and f_krd are the Checkbox controls
    IF NOT (f_na.Checked OR f_dep.Checked OR f_krd.Checked) THEN
        MessageBox("Attention", "A new AO code must be filled in")

        RETURN 2 // Reject the text input data but allow focus to change
    END IF
END IF

RETURN 0
```